# Upgrading Material-ui 0.10.1 to 0.17 with hundreds of errors

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

It looks like there were massive changes between these versions and we are actually having to upgrade 40 libraries to upgrade React.js and material-ui is the one that is giving us the most problems.

It doesn't appear there is documentation on how to make these changes. For instance, material-ui/utils/key-code is removed, but we use it in our code and I have no idea how to replace it to something else. Directory structures look like they have changed a lot, sometimes as simple as capitalizing the director name, some moved to other directories.

How do I fix the following...

```
ERROR in ./js/components/datePicker/datePicker.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui/utils/key-code'

ERROR in ./js/components/home/action-items/tabs/tabs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui/mixins/style-propable.js'

ERROR in ./js/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui//styles/theme-manager' 

ERROR in ./js/styles/iq7theme.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui//utils/color-manipulator'

ERROR in ./js/components/case/notes.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/addons'

ERROR in ./js/components/inputs/taxIdInput.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react/lib/ReactInputSelection'
```

Thanks

Comment: style-propable.js I just removed completely, didn't see it used. Same with ReactInputSelect and I think react/addons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what took you so long?! That release is 20 months old! :-)

Now to get you up-to-date:

Breaking changes are documented in the release notes: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases

You will need to start here:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases?after=v0.11.0

I would suggest upgrading one breaking release at a time, fix the issues and move on. You will need to keep the peer dependencies in sync as you progress.

The directory structure re-org happened in 0.15.0, and is documented here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases?after=v0.15.0

As mentioned there, we provided a codemod to update the imports in your project for you: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-codemod#material-ui-codemod

If you were using an internal utility (naughty!) that has gone away, you can simply copy that code from the last version that had it to your project, and update the imports. You will now be responsible for maintaining that code.

Alternatively, you could look at the material-ui source, and see what replaced it - presumably for good reason. (Hint: `keycode`)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Matt.

We are a startup, I am working 14 hour days, and could never get to upgrading because of all the other priorities. Like getting to production and starting to get clients. I have already spent 2+ days on this upgrade and still not finished (webpack not working)

I think I have now managed to get material-ui upgraded. Wish I had seen there was a coded to upgrade as I had to manually do it all. ;) And I copied the two classes we still needed. one was key-code, so not really a class, and I did try looking at source and couldn't figure out its replacement. ;)

Comment: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/05280483dbbc29e56edd8f3644721679b55d4d73/package.json#L51

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think I tried first using that, but that there are some keys missing that were in the other key-code class that Material-UI created that we use. ;) I copied the older Material-UI key-code class into our codebase going forward.